# Replacing `$latex whatever$ with $$whatever$$ in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I want to replace `$latex some_math_tex_formula_with_spaces$` with `$$Some_math_formula_with_spaces$$` in vim using inbuilt search and replace capabilities of vim.

I tried `:%s/$latex\(\w\+\)$/$$\1$$/g`, but I can't replace all occurrences, somehow, it matches only one or two ?

For example : I want to change this `$latex D = \prod_{i=1}^{n_e}(1-{p_i})$` into `$$D = \prod_{i=1}^{n_e}(1-{p_i})$$`.

Comment: Why down-vote? You can move it some other SE site, if you think this is not a right place for it.

Comment: What did you try? How did it fail?

Comment: I tried `:%s/$latex\(\w\+\)$/$$\1$$/g` but I can't replace all occurrences. Somehow, it matches only one or two. I am still experimenting with it.

Comment: What’s “whatever”? A word? A mathematical expression? An arbitrary LaTeX expression? Can it contain nested math environments (i.e. something like this: `$1 + \text{foo $a$}$`)?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Sorry for being ambiguous. its a math expression. Updated the statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try saying:

```
%s/$latex\s*\([^$]*\)\$/$$\1$$/g
```